# Oracle SQL wildcard not returning expected result set

Tags: sql, oracle, wildcard

I have used and continue to use wild cards in simple Oracle SQL statements.  This one is not working and I really don't know why.  The SQL below returns 0 rows but if I remove the wildcard character "%" it returns the single row as expected.  I would have thought both statements should return the same result set:

```
select * from my_table where ident_num='%98511';     -- No rows

select * from my_table where ident_num='98511';      -- 1 row
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `LIKE` for the wildcard query?

Comment: You are using an equality predicate not a Like predicate, why do you presume they are the same?

Comment: Yup.  I just saw that.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from my_table where ident_num='%98511'
```

This will return all the rows with the exact string '%98511

```
select * from my_table where ident_num like '%98511'
```

Shoul do what you intend to do